# UB указатели и ссылки

Tags: c++

Что конкретно произойдёт при компиляции?

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main()
 {
    int a;
    int *pa=&a;
    int &ra=*pa;
    delete pa;
    std::cout << ra;
 }
```

Comment: @Abyx получается перед `delete` надо делать поверки?

Comment: А если это происходит в другой функции и удаление происходит автоматически?

Comment: При компиляции не произойдёт ничего интересного. А вот во время выполнения...

Comment: Язык C++ построен на джентльменских соглашениях. Вы соглашаетесь сами, без принуждения со стороны компилятора не удалять при помощи `delete` то, что не было создано при помощи `new`. А система соглашается правильно работать. Если вы нарушите вашу часть соглашения, система имеет право нарушить и свою.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае имеет место неопределенное поведение, так как вы не можете применять оператор `delete` к указателям, которые не указывают на область памяти, полученной с помощью оператора `new`.

В этом предложении

```
delete pa;
```

вы пытаетесь освободить память, которая был распределена компилятором для переменной с автоматическом сроком жизни. Поэтому может произойти все, что угодно, включая аварийное завершение программы.

Если бы вы выделили память для объекта динамически, используя оператор `new`, как, например,

```
 #include <iostream>
 int main()
 {
    int *pa = new int();
    int &ra=*pa;
    delete pa;
    std::cout << ra;
 }
```

то в этом слкчае программа имела бы неопределенное поведение по другой причине: ссылка `ra` оказывается "подвешенной" после удаления объекта в предложении

```
delete pa;
```

Поэтому результат выполнения предложения

```
std::cout << ra;
```

не определен, и программа также может завершиться аварийно, так как происходит попытка обратиться к уже удаленному объекту и освобожденной области памяти.

Что касается вопроса

> Что конкретно произойдёт при компиляции?

то все зависит от конкретного компилятора. Компилятор может успешно скомпилировать код, а может выдать диагностическое сообщение.